# How to edit an appended div

Tags: javascript

I have a button which creates form elements on click .

My `addelement` function looks like this

```
function addElement(){
    to = document.getElementById('top');
    newId = document.createElement('div');
    id = 'my'+this.num;
    newId.setAttribute('id', id );
    newId.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' value = ''>";
    to.appendChild(newId);
    this.num++;
}
```

... which renders the text input field to a form with ID = 'top' and creates a dynamic div for every form element

Now once the element is inside the form, I want to know a way to edit that element. How could that be done?

Comment: You tagged the question as jQuery but you are not using it, and did not mention it. Did you need a jQuery solution, or a plain javascript one ?

Comment: use this document.body.appendChild(newdiv);

Comment: what kind of edits you want to do with that newly created element?

Comment: What do you mean by `edit that element`?

Comment: sorry i want a javascript solution...edit would mean changing the property and the attributes of the appended elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assign `id` to this element:

```
newId.setAttribute('id', id );
```

You can get this element by id using `getElementById` function:

```
var elementToEdit = document.getElementById('my123');
```

If you need to get `input` element, simple write:

```
var inputToEdit = elementToEdit.childNodes[0];
```

But I will reccomend you to not create elements from string. ie:

```
newId.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' value = ''>";
```

the better is to use `createElement` function and then append it to newly created `div`